# Determine actual width of text in plot

Tags: r, text, plot, margin

I'm plotting a factor on the x-axis, so each point is labeled with the name of the factor.  Since the text would overlap if plotted horizontally, I'm plotting it all vertically.  However, I then will occasionally run into issues with the x-axis margin not being large enough.  So, my question: Is there a way to determine how long a text string will be when plotted (in, say, inches)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `strwidth` in the `graphics` package.

To use it, first plot your graph. Then simply call `strwidth("your string")`
eg:

```
library(graphics)

plot(1:5)

strwidth("hello")
#  [1] 0.2640991
strwidth(" a longer string\n with multiple lines asdfsdfjkdsrew")
#  [1] 1.875732

strwidth("hello", units="inches")
#  [1] 0.3521322
strwidth("hello", units="figure")
#  [1] 0.05030459
```

---

If you are plotting rotated text, It's possible you may want to use `strheight` (analogous functionality)